# Files explorer crashes on Ubuntu Bionic Beaver

Tags: linux, nautilus

I have an issue where almost every time I use the files file explorer it crashes and fails to open.
I can only open files by right clicking on it and then going to "Open with other applications."

I already tried to reinstall nautilus but could not resolve the problem.

I get following in syslog:

```
Mar 15 12:47:36 zeutec-dev nautilus[10527]: Error 71 (Protocol error) dispatching to Wayland display.
Mar 15 12:47:36 zeutec-dev gnome-shell[3241]: Object Meta.WindowActor (0x55592385b7d0), has been already finalized. Impossible to get any property from it.
Mar 15 12:47:36 zeutec-dev org.gnome.Shell.desktop[3241]: == Stack trace for context 0x555920953320 ==
```

Need some direction.

Comment: The direction should be that where you can find a forum for Linux vor Ubuntu questions ;-) SO is about programming

Comment: Yes, this question belongs on [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/). However, since we are provided with no migration path for AskUbuntu (and really no other flagging option than to say that it is blatantly off-topic), I will instead leave a comment and not flag the question at all.

Answer (score 2):

If you would like to debug this, you should do the following:

Terminate running nautilus (GNOME files):

```
nautilus -q
```

Since this was a Wayland protocol error (`Error 71 (Protocol error) dispatching to Wayland display.`)

You should then try to run nautilus with wayland debug info.

```
env WAYLAND_DEBUG=1 ./nautilus
```

Then make it crash and look at the terminal output.

You could then either read up on Wayland to try to understand what's happening, or just copy the output and file a bug in the gnome bug tracker.

Comment: Thank you for help. I did dist-upgrade and reinstalled nautilus and then rebooted the system. Finally, issue was solved.